# Thrift client cpp : how to get server close event

Tags: c++, thrift

I have a non-blocking thrift-based server in c++. Thrift version is 0.10.0.
Is there any way to get server close event at client's side? I've found out the `TTransport` throws an exception in case server has been closed but is there any way to get this notification in an async manner?